# Any ideas on how SqlWorkflowInstanceStore could be made to work with a different schema?

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation-4

Thank you in advance for any input or advice!

I am using WF4 in a large project that requires long running workflow persistence.  For deployment consistency reasons, it would be helpful to use an alternate schema name for instance store objects.  For example, System.Activities.DurableInstancing.InstanceTable would become DurableInstancing.InstanceTable, etc.

Updating the SQL scripts to accomplish this server-side is not difficult, but from what I can tell, there is no way to modify the default schema used by SqlWorkflowInstanceStore when generating commands.  It appears the schema name is read from SqlWorkflowInstanceStoreConstants.DefaultSchema, which is a constant (as the name implies).  SqlWorkflowInstanceStore is sealed and it seems to be quite a task to roll your own InstanceStore, so I'm reluctant to pursue that option.

Does anyone know of simpler way to do this that I might be missing?  Also, I am aware that changing the schema name would add steps to applying future instance store updates, but can anyone foresee other potential problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never tried that but as far as I know the SqlWorkflowInstanceStore only calls stored procedures. All of those need to be in the System.Activities.DurableInstancing DB scheme but you should be able to move the tables and views to another DB scheme.

Quite frankly I would probably never do that as that would mean I am no longer in a supported scenario and see no benefit. If for some reason you need to query the System.Activities.DurableInstancing tabled/view and because the way your app is set up that needs to be in another DB scheme I would just create views there pointing to the original tables.

Comment: That sounds reasonable, thanks!  I'm leaning heavily toward accessing instance data from within the app via views as you suggested, with the idea of possibly implementing a custom instance store sometime down the road.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing your own InstanceStore isn't difficult. We were in a similar situation, we really didn't want to have two schemas, ours and the Workflow SQL. We implemented our own InstanceStore and it's about 280 lines of code. We had to add one table to our schema and a couple fields to existing tables.

I would encourage you to try implementing your own InstanceStore.

Comment: @John Thanks for the reply!  I'm very interested in creating a custom instance store (likely repository based).  Did you run into any locking or concurrency issues?

Comment: It would be difficult to share the production code but, if I can find our "proof of concept", I'll share that.

Comment: We did not run into locking/concurrency issues because we were adding Workflow to an app that already has a locking/concurrency framework in place.